# May i know how to customize animated icon, i want to do like before clicking the floating button it showing +icon, after clicking it shows x icon

Tags: flutter

May i know how to customize animated icon, i want to do like before clicking the floating button it showing +icon, after clicking it shows x icon?

I want to do like before clicking the floating button it showing +icon, after clicking it shows x icon